# AngularJS PUT works, POST returns undefined scope values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

With the code I can update the users that are listed, but adding new Users doesn't work. The scope of the input for new items is undefined always. It does submit something, but without the values I filled in, in the form. The `console.log($scope.newMail)` return `undefined` for example.

```
<script>
function UsersController($scope, $http, $location) {
    $http.get('/users').success(function(users) {
        $scope.users = users;
    });

    $scope.addUser = function(user) {
        var user = {
            name:   $scope.newName, // with hardcoding values here it does work
            email:      $scope.newMail // but with newValues, both stay null always
        };
        console.log(user); // returns undefined values
        $http.post('/users', user);
    }

    $scope.updateUser = function(user) {
        $http.put('/users/'+user.id, user);
    }
}
</script>


<section ng-controller="UsersController">

    <!-- ng-repeat -->
    <div ng-repeat="user in users">
        <form ng-submit="updateUser(user)">

            <input type="hidden" ng-model="user.id" value="{{ user.id }}"/>
            <input type="text" value="{{ user.name }}" ng-model="user.name" />
            <input type="email" value="{{ user.email }}" ng-model="user.email" />

            <button type="submit" />
        </form>


        <section ng-show="toggleForm">

            <form ng-submit="addUser(user)">
                <input type="text" ng-model="newName" required />
                <input type="email" ng-model="newMail" required />

                <button type="submit" ng-click="toggleForm = !toggleForm"/>
            </form>

        </section>

        <a ng-click="toggleForm = !toggleForm"><p>New user</p></a>

    </div>
</section>
```

Can't figure out what is wrong. What am I missing?

I implemented solution #3:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'mail' of undefined
    at setter (//urlassets/app.js:3:26728)
    at extend.assign (//urlassets/app.js:5:29229)
    at $setViewValue (//urlassets/app.js:6:5077)
    at //urlassets/app.js:4:31686
    at Scope.$eval (//urlassets/app.js:4:9722)
    at Scope.$apply (//urlassets/app.js:4:10068)
    at Scope.$delegate.__proto__.$apply (<anonymous>:855:30)
    at HTMLInputElement.listener (//urlassets/app.js:4:31663)
    at //urlassets/app.js:1:29072
    at forEach (//urlassets/app.js:1:8278)
```

And looks like: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3nhkhcsz3g6d6iy/test.mov

Comment: are you sure your backend service is working as expected?

Comment: Yes. Tried it with cURL and it works. It does submit something, but with null values. When I do ```console.log($scope.newMail);```, then I get ```undefined``` in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is with scope inheritance. So there should be a couple of alternative:

## Alternative # 1

Use an object (e.g., *newuser*) and bind the inputs to that object, so you send it to the controller method as a whole.

HTML

```
<form ng-submit="addUser(newuser)">
    <input type="text" ng-model="newuser.name" required />
    <input type="email" ng-model="newuser.mail" required />

    <button type="submit" ng-click="toggleForm = !toggleForm"/>
</form>
```

JS

```
$scope.addUser = function(user) {
    $http.post('/users', user);
}
```

## Alternative #2

I suspect that the form is creating a new child scope, so that will be the reason why the value is returning undefined. You could explicitly bind to the $parent scope, so that the method from controller can see it.

```
<form ng-submit="addUser(user)">
    <input type="text" ng-model="$parent.newName" required />
    <input type="email" ng-model="$parent.newMail" required />

    <button type="submit" ng-click="toggleForm = !toggleForm"/>
</form>
```

## Alternative #3

HTML

```
<form ng-submit="addUser(newuser[$index])">
    <input type="text" ng-model="newuser[$index].name" required />
    <input type="email" ng-model="newuser[$index].mail" required />

    <button type="submit" ng-click="toggleForm = !toggleForm"/>
</form>
```

JS

```
$scope.newuser = {};
$scope.addUser = function(user) {
    $http.post('/users', user);
}
```

Comment: But when you added something now, with the addUser, that succeed. And you wanna add a new one, the form still has the same values as the last added item. And when you change the text in the form, the text also changes in the list of that item. 
Is there a way to get a whole new form, when you want to add a new User? ```Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys.```

Comment: You could use the $index to create individual 'newUsers', take a look at alternative#3 on the updated answer

Comment: Did that. But then I can't type anymore: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3nhkhcsz3g6d6iy/test.mov

Comment: Can you setup a Plunker? Then we can resolve this faster

Comment: I added the following to the ng-repeat: ```ng-repeat="user in users track by $index"```.

See my edit in startpost.

Comment: I'll need to see more code to help you resolve this. The video uploaded actually doesn't help. Better make a simple example on jsfiddle or Plunker and I'll help you solve this.

Comment: So you identified the problem "I think your problem is with scope inheritance." 
Then you jumped directly to alternatives ? why don't you try to solve the root problem instead of throwing alternatives ?